# Efficient way to find all cycles whose length little than N and that contain node P in undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a large graph with about one million nodes and four millions edges. I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find all cycles whose length little than `N` and that contain a specified node `P`.

More specifically, `3 < N < 5`, there are serveral nodes `P` that need to be processed.

I have tried naive `depth first search` algorithm and found it too slow to satisfy my demand. Is there any better solution to this problem?

Comment: Try a breadth-first search, keeping a record of all the visited nodes. You should then be able to find a loop of size N within N/2 steps starting from P.

Comment: I am wondering if pruning would solve the problem, marking the distance of each node on a path from the starting node `P` during `depth first search`. When the search encounters this node again, it is decided whether to search further by checking the distance.

Comment: *"I have tried naive depth first search algorithm"*: DFS should be fine. Please show your implementation (minimal code).

Comment: @TsiaoWang Yes, you should definitely mark the distance of each node. The DFS should not search beyond depth N.

Comment: "found it too slow"  Yo do not say how slow is too slow.  Since you are looking in the close neighborhood of a single specified node, then you should get the answer in a few milliseconds, no matter how large or small the entire network should be.  If your execution time is in the seconds and/or varies with the size of the network, then there is something badly wrong with your algorithm.  You will need to post your algorithm.

Comment: The DFS should not search beyond N that is true but nor should it search beyond a node it has seen before. If it is P, the search is over, but if it is some other node, it is a subcycle. The DFS may never find a way out of it and crash with a stack overflow.